# How to use validation on EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I'm working on a mvc5 project.
A have generated a view containing following html/razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.ReservationDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.ReservationDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.ReservationDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a EditorTemplate so I can use [this](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) datepicker:

```
@model DateTime?

<input id="@Html.IdForModel()" name="@Html.NameForModel()" value="@ViewData["Date"]" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true" />
```

and included the template in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.ReservationDate, new { Date = @Model.Reservation.ReservationDate})
```

The problem is, I lose the validation I defined via the data annotation in my model, because

```
class="text-box single-line valid" type="date" data-val-required="The Datum field is required." data-val-date="The field Datum must be a date." data-val="true"
```

gets overridden by the EditorTemplate. I could include that code in my template, but that way its hard-coded. For me, that's not a option.

So I was wondering, how can I add those html annotations in a better way?

This is the property from my model, with its DataAnnotions:

```
[UIHint("DatePicker")]
[DisplayName("Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Not a valid date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReservationDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a little extra work for yourself by creating the input HTML element instead of using Html.TextBoxFor(). Try doing this instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { @class = "fieldDate", @Value = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "" })
```

In your javascript code:

```
$('.fieldDate').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
    autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Also, does the jquery datepicker() method overwrite the HTML attributes?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Although I found a solution using the "Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes" Dictionary and adding validation messages by fetching the value from the keys, your solution is less far fetched and therefor answering my problem.